# why do we need to burn a root file system in embedded system development

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

You know when we do embedded system development,we'll burn a root file system **first**(like *cramfs* etc.) and then  burn a Linux kernel.Since there's already a file system in the Linux kernel, why should we burn a root file system first?

Comment: Did you consider googling "busybox"?

Comment: I've deleted that question(on busybox),but the first question wasn't answered.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "file system in the Linux kernel". If a RAMFS is enough in your case, I think you don't need to have a separate rootfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux kernel contains scheduler code, memory management driver, file system management driver, generic device drivers, IPC driver, network driver, architecture specific device drivers, firmware code and kernel headers etc. **File system is not part of linux kernel**. But file system managing drivers are part of linux kernel. So we need to have root file system either **ramfs** or **cramfs** or **nfs** etc.., once after the linux kernel is up will gets itself linked/attached to the file system accordingly. **Better to use nfs file system during development stage**, need to setup some files before using **nfs**.

Answer (score 1):

no, rootfs is not first, this order is right.

1. install bootloader
2. install kernel
3. install rootfs

Comment: This is not a meaningful answer, since there's no real consistent meaning to ordering in this context.

Answer (score -1):

So basically you can use any filesystem with the same kernel image without recompiling it unless the support for that filesystem (the driver to handle the filesystem) has been compiled in the kernel.